# jupyter notebook and github.

Tags: git, github, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I have made a jupyter notebook and want to commit and push on github. I have windows operating system and never worked on github. Can anyone please help me out about how can I do it from scratch?

Answer (score 4):

As long as you have [Git setup locally](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/), and you have [created a new Repo on GitHub side](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository/), you can:

- `git init .` a local repo where your files are
- add the remote (empty) repo URL

  ```
    git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/<myrepo>
  ```
- add, commit and push your files, including  `.ipynb` jupiter ones.

See "[Working with Jupyter Notebook files on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-jupyter-notebook-files-on-github/)"

> When you add Jupyter Notebook or IPython Notebook files with a `.ipynb` extension on GitHub, they will render as static HTML files in your repository.
>
> The interactive features of the notebook, such as custom JavaScript plots, will not work in your repository on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks VonC. I found that in the main page of repository there is an upload button using which I can upload any file. Would that be correct to use it? And I am also worried about if I make changes in the repository how these changes will reflect on a website, I am working on a project in which I have to make a jupyter notebook with instructions and hints for students. Can you please suggest me anything on this?

Comment: @Nizam You can use the upload button, but using a local repo and pushing back is easier. Check out GitHub Desktop for instance. (https://desktop.github.com/). As for the website, I don't have enough information. Jupyter pages are directly visible on GitHub, so that alone could be enough of a web site for your need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this jupyter extension. It will enable you to directly upload your ipython notebooks to github.

https://github.com/sat28/githubcommit

I have also created a video demonstrating the steps -
[youtube link](https://youtu.be/vKx_4zFvOi8)